# Small notification light to detect electric current on large cable

Tags: current

```
                |================================= |------------|
Power Outlet 220V           Large Cable            | Water Pump |
                |================================= |------------|
                                       |
                                       |
A small 3 watt LED? (o)=----------------
```

I want to have a small notification light bulb nearby, to indicate that an automatic water pump located around 40 meters away is currently on.

The pump uses a large cable. Is there a safe way to light this bulb using just a small cable?

Comment: You need to clarify your requirements. (1) Do you want to check that power is available to the pump (voltage measurement) or that the pump is drawing current (current measurement)? (2) Can you split the cable to accept a current transformer on one wire (because the sum of the currents in the two wires will be zero)? (3) Are you sure you need a 3 W LED? That's enough to light up a room. [Edit] the details into your question - not in the comments.

Comment: On what side of the cable is the switch that controls the pump? On the left side (where the LED will be) or on the remote pump side?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at a current transformer . AC    Amps in your large 220V pump cable could become safe isolated milliamps which could be rectified to drive a led .

Answer (score 1):

The hard part is doing this *safely*.

The AC power wires throw a magnetic field proportional to the current.  But... You can't just clamp the outside of the cable, because the hot and neutral wire magnetic fields will cancel each other out.

You need a line splitter, and a safe, approved one [is made](http://www.mastech-group.com/products.php?PNo=246) for use with clamp ammeters. It provides electrical connection via ordinary plugs and sockets.

[image]

Inside the "10X" area will be a fairly strong magnetic field when the pump is drawing current.  You should be able to detect that via a variety of ways, from magnetic reed switch to hall effect device.